# Highlight part of a search result in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, string

Ok so I have a bit of PHP code which outputs results pulled from the Wordpress database.

```
if ($searchPostResults) :
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($searchPostResults as $pagePosts)
        echo '<li><span class="searchResult"><a href="' . get_the_permalink($pagePosts->ID) . '" title="">' . get_the_title($pagePosts->ID) . '</a></span></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
else :
    ?>
        <p>No Results</p>
    <?php
endif;
```

So in each result the keyword will appear.
I would like to make that keyword bold.

The keyword is stored here:

```
$searchVal = (isset($_POST["searchVal"])) ? $_POST["searchVal"] : "";
```

Example:
I'm a **search** result.

What would be the best way about doing this for each result.
I thought about using grep and substrings but this seems a bit long winded.

Cheers

Comment: hmm maybe preg_replace is the best way to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **preg_replace** method we can highlight the search text.

Below is the sample PHP snippet:

```
<?php 
    $result = "I'm a search result."; 
    $searchVal = "search";
    $sk = explode(" ",$searchVal); 
    $result = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $sk) .')/iu', '<strong class="highlighter">\0</strong>', $result);

    echo $result;
?>
```

Use below pattern to match only words:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $sk) .')\b/iu', '<strong class="highlighter">\0</strong>', $result);
```

While Integrating this on your WP code assign title to $result

```
$result = get_the_title($pagePosts->ID);
```

In addition to this you can use css to apply styles to the highlighted text.

```
strong.highlighter { 
    background-color:yellow;
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. this almost works as desired. although it highlight this title `How to Repl<b>a</b>ce Jets on <b>a Camping Stove</b>` like so. I would like it to be like this `How to Replace Jets on <b>a Camping Stove</b>` Here is an image of the problem. http://imgur.com/KPieRYR

Comment: use the pattern as    /\b('.implode('|', $sk) .')\b/iu

This will highlight the word matches only

Answer (score 0):

Simply use str_replace:

`str_replace($searchVal, '<strong>'.$searchVal.'</strong>', get_the_title($pagePosts->ID))`

to replace `get_the_title($pagePosts->ID))`.

If it doesn't match, the title will pass thru unchanged.

(Note: this will not deal with case mismatches as is.)a